# Combine two SQL statements with arithmetic (not joining per se)

Tags: mysql, select

I have a plugin that counts helpful votes for reviews on my site ('helpful', 'funny', 'cool', and it gives the option of adding other descriptors as well. So I've added 'not helpful'.

Now I'm trying to customize the query used to display the reviews with the most votes by taking 'not helpful' votes into account (subtracting them from the helpful votes) instead of just counting a total of all votes.

So originally the query used for this was:

```
SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

And I've found that I can count the helpful votes (where the number in the 'rate' column is 0, 1, or 2), like so:

```
SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` <3 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

And I can count the non-helpful votes (where the number in the 'rate' column is 3), like so:

```
SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` >2 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

But what I can't figure out is how to combine these two select statements such that the top 5 'count' results show a difference of the counts from each query.

I don't want a union because no subtraction is done, and I've tried various permutations of multiple selects, but can't manage to work this out.

Any suggestions?

An example table: [Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcvpD.png)

In the example above, if all votes are counted blindly, review #4 is ranked higher than review #10, but if not-helpful votes are taken into account, #10 is ranked higher with a net total of 1 versus review #4's net total of 0.

Make sense?

Comment: You can simply just add it into your select statement. like select review_id, (query1) as query1, (query2) as query2 from ...

Comment: I could do that if I want two independent results, but I'm wanting to update the aggregate total returned by the query with the result of the second query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.review_id,b.review_id,a.count,b.count from
(SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` <3 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5) as a
left join
(SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` >2 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5) as b
on a.review_id = b.review_id
```

this is work if `review_id` of first query = `review_id` of second query otherwise you can use also <> to `both`.

other option use `union all`

```
SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` <3 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
union all
SELECT review_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `wp_reviews_ratings` where `rate` >2 GROUP BY review_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, although your first solution returns the following (not what I'm looking for): http://imgur.com/a/OvDzI

And your second solution returns an error: "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: You can remove the order by clause.. it was in a hurry lately.

Comment: Yes, but the Order By is important, otherwise it won't rank the top most useful comments.